# How does this division work? $\frac{\;\frac{6^6}{1}\;}{2^{-3}}\cdot2^{-10}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I came across this division and can't wrap my head around how it is solved:
$$\frac{\;\;\frac{6^6}{1}\;\;}{2^{-3}}\cdot2^{-10}$$
They subtract the exponent of $2^{-10}$ from the denominator's exponent $2^{-3}$:
$$2^{-3-(-10)}$$
Which gives us:
$$\frac{\;\;\frac{6^6}{1}\;\;}{2^7}$$
If anyone knows what is actually being done here I would appreciate it!

Comment: Do you understand that $\frac {b^m}{b^n} = b^{m-n}= \frac 1{b^{n-m}}$?  That's all there is to it.  If $m = -10$ and $n=-3$ you have $\frac 1{2^{-3}} *2^{-10} = 2^{-10 -(-3)} = \frac 1{2^{-3-(-10)}}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $a^{-n}=\frac{1}{a^n}$ and $a^b \cdot a^c = a^{b+c}$.

$$\frac{1}{2^{-3}}\cdot 2^{-10}=\frac{1}{2^{-3}}\cdot \frac1{2^{10}}=\frac1{2^{10-3}}$$

Answer (score 0):

There is usually more than one way to simplify an expression.
I would probably have chosen to multiply numerator and denominator by $2^3$ in order to deal with exponents only and not with fractions.

Another approach would be to multiply numerator and denominator by $2^{10},$
which would cancel the $2^{-10}$ on the right of the fraction.

But a slightly different approach was taken by whoever did it the way you saw. Apparently they decided to divide by $2^{-10},$ which has the same effect as multiplying by $2^{10}$, but the direct interpretation of $2^a$ divided by $2^b$ is $2^{a-b},$ and in this example $a=-3$ and $b=-10,$
so $a-b$ is literally $-3-(-10).$

But for goodness sake, why didn’t they simplify away the division by $1$ before tackling the rest of it?

Answer (score 0):

$b^nb^m = b^{n+m}$ and $b^{-n} = \frac 1b$ and $\frac {b^n}{b^m} = b^{n-m} = \frac 1{b^{m-n}}$.  That is all that is going on.

$\frac {BLAH}{\frac 1{2^{-3}}\cdot 2^{-10}}=$

$\frac {BLAH}{\frac 1{2^{-3}}\frac 1{2^{-(-10)}}}=\frac {BLAH}{\frac 1{2^{-3 - (-10)}}}$

Frankly seems like a convoluted way to make things as hard as possible and to make the negative signs as many and as confusing as possible.

I'd have just done:

$\frac{6^6}{\frac 1{2^{-3}}\cdot 2^{-10}}=$

$\frac {(2\cdot 3)^6}{2^3\cdot 2^{-10}}=$

$\frac {2^6\cdot 3^6}{2^{-7}}=$

$2^6\cdot 3^6 \cdot 2^7 = 2^{13}\cdot 3^6$.

.....

Oh.... I now see the expression was supposed to be $\frac {\frac {6^6}1}{2^{-3}}\cdot 2^{-10}$ and not $\frac{6^6}{\frac 1{2^{-3}}\cdot 2^{-10}}$.

That doesn't change me comments and answer.  But sheesh what kind of lunatic wrote this problem solely for the purpose of confusion?

We have $\frac {BLAH}{2^{-3}}\cdot 2^{-10} =$

$\frac {BLAH}{2^{-3}2^{-(-10)}} = \frac {BLAH}{2^{-3-(-10)}}$.

But I'd do:

$\frac {\frac {6^6}1}{2^{-3}}\cdot 2^{-10}=$

$\frac {6^6}{2^{-3}}\cdot 2^{-10}=$

$6^6\cdot 2^3 \cdot 2^{-10} =$

$6^6 \cdot 2^{-7}= $

$(2\cdot 3)^6 \cdot 2^{-7}=$

$2^6\cdot 3^6 \cdot 2^{-7}=$

$2^{-1}\cdot 3^6=$

$\frac {3^6}2$.

=====

Or we could simply do:

$\frac {\frac {6^6}1}{2^{-3}} \cdot 2^{-10}$

$\frac {\frac {6^6}1}{\frac 1{2^3}}\cdot \frac 1{2^{10}}=$

$\frac {\frac {6^6}1}{\frac 1{2^3}2^{10}}=$

$\frac {\frac {6^6}1}{2^7}$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\frac{\;\;\dfrac{6^6}{1}\;\;}{2^{-3}}\cdot2^{-10}
&=\frac{6^6}{2^{-3}}\cdot 2^{-10}\qquad&\text{(simplify the denominator)}\\
&=6^6\cdot 2^3\cdot 2^{-10}\qquad &(\frac{1}{2^{-3}}=2^3)\\
&=6^6\cdot 2^{3+(-10)}\qquad &(2^a2^b=2^{a+b})\\
&=6^6\cdot 2^{-7}\qquad &\text{(simplify)}\\
&=\frac{6^6}{2^7}\qquad &(2^{-7}=\frac{1}{2^7})
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Making all exponents positive,

$$\frac{\dfrac{6^6}{1}}{2^{-3}}2^{-10}=\frac{6^6\cdot 2^3}{1\cdot2^{10}}=\frac{3^6\cdot2^6\cdot2^3}{2^{10}}=\frac{729}2.$$

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a problem of confusing notation. If you read the expression as (which is what I first assumed is written)
$$
6^6\div\frac{1}{2^{-3}}\cdot 2^{-10}=\frac{729}{128}.
$$
There is no simplification like the one you wrote. However, if you read it as
$6^6\cdot\frac{1}{2^{-3}}\cdot 2^{-10}=\frac{729}{2}=\frac{6^6}{2^7}$ you get the right answer. I'm not really sure why the question bothered to divide $6^6$ by 1.

Answer (score -3):

First off, the way in which the problem is typeset is almost *intended* to cause confusion.  Adding some parentheses and not using `\dfrac` everywhere should make it easier to understand the expression:

$$\frac{\left(\frac{6^6}{1}\right)}{2^{-3}} \cdot 2^{-10}. $$

Division is the inverse operation of multiplication and so, rather than thinking of the problem as a division problem, it might be easier to think of it as the multiplication of several fractions.  Specifically,

$$\frac{\left(\frac{6^6}{1}\right)}{2^{-3}} \cdot 2^{-10}
= 6^6 \cdot \frac{1}{2^{-3}} \cdot 2^{-10}. $$

One of the fundamental properties of exponents is that (under appropriate hypotheses) $a^{-n} = \frac{1}{a^n}$, and so we can further simplify this expression to

$$ 6^6 \cdot \frac{1}{2^{-3}} \cdot 2^{-10}
= 6^6 \cdot 2^{3} \cdot \frac{1}{2^{10}}
= 6^6 \cdot \frac{2^{3}}{2^{10}}. $$

Finally, another property of exponents is that
$$ \frac{a^m}{a^n} = a^{m-n}. $$
Applying this to the last result gives

$$ 6^6 \cdot \frac{2^{3}}{2^{10}}
= 6^6 \cdot 2^{3-10}
= 6^6 \cdot 2^{-7}
\overset{\text{or}}{=} \frac{6^6}{2^7}. $$

Personally, I would also probably use the fact that $(ab)^n = a^n b^n$ to rewrite $6^6 = 2^6\cdot 3^6$, and conclude by writing
$$ 6^6 \cdot 2^{-7} = 2^6\cdot 3^6 \cdot 2^{-7}
= 2^{6-7} \cdot 3^6
= 2^{-1} \cdot 3^6
\overset{\text{or}}{=} \frac{3^6}{2}, $$
but perhaps this is not part of the intended exercise.